# Trying to use image from URL with Kohana Image class

Tags: image, alias, kohana-3, getimagesize, realpath

I'm trying to use an image from a URL with Kohana image class. http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Image

Is this possible or does the image always have to be local to the project?

I'm accessing the image like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/temp/myimage.jpg
```

from the same site.

However the temp folder in the above URL is actually an Alias in Apache so is outside of the document root.

Can anyone shed any light on a solution?

The kohana image library says its not an image because it either fails

```
realpath($file);
```

or

```
getimagesize($file);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image does have to be local to the project.

What you can do is grab a copy off the remote and save it to your project and serve that.

```
$offsite_path = 'http://example.com/images/steve-buscemi.jpg';
$local_copy = Remote::get($offsite_path);
$local_path  = 'images/steve-buscemi.jpg';
file_put_contents($local_path, $local_copy);
echo HTML::image($local_path);
```

There is a [feature request to allow for remote image access](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/3417) using the Image module.